# Can mount a USB thumbdrive on Mac, but it is not shown in Finder

Tags: mac, usb, mount, finder

Using an Apple MPB mid-2014 and MacOS 10.12.6, I can mount any number of USB thumbdrives. The drives appear as mounts on the Desktop, but no longer appear in a Finder window under the Devices section. They used to do so.

The devices are visible via the command line as mounted filesystems under /Volumes. The `diskutil` utility may be used to mount or unmount them. Similarly, they appear on the Desktop and may be ejected from the right-click menu.

The Finder preferences to show external mounts in Finder windows has been selected.

I have tried using DiskUtility to repair disk permissions. No errors were discovered.

Does anyone know how to repair the system state so that mounted USB devices appear in the Finder windows? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See if the Finder's sidebar preferences still list external disk.

- Go to Finder's Preferences in the Finder menu, or hit cmd+,
- Open the Sidebar tab
- Under Devices, check "External disks"

You can also try relaunching Finder by holding down the Option Key when right-clicking (or 2 finger-tap) on the Finder icon in the Dock and selecting "Relaunch"

Comment: That doesn't do it. As stated, the Finder preferences to show external mounts in Finder windows has been selected. The problem survives both a Finder restart as well as a reboot.